# Returning a method not giving same result as returning a variable

Tags: c#

Suppose :

```
returnedDeck = player.DoYouHaveAny(value);
MessageBox(returnDeck.Count);
```

Now, here's the problem. With this method :

```
public Deck DoYouHaveAny(Value value)
    {
        textBoxOnForm.Text += name + " has " + cards.PullOutValues(value).Count + " " + Card.Plural(value) + Environment.NewLine;

        return cards.PullOutValues(value);
    }
```

I will always get returnedDeck.Count = 0

But if I change the method to do that :

```
public Deck DoYouHaveAny(Value value)
    {
        deckToReturn = cards.PullOutValues(value);
        textBoxOnForm.Text += name + " has " + cards.PullOutValues(value).Count + " " + Card.Plural(value) + Environment.NewLine;

        return deckToReturn;
    }
```

Now the returnedDeck.Count will return some values.
Just pure curiosity, but why can't I use "return cards.PullOutValues(value);" directly ?

Here's the code of PullOutValue :

```
public Deck PullOutValues(Value value)
    {
        Deck deckToReturn = new Deck(new Card[] { });
        for (int i = deck.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (deck[i].Value == value)
                deckToReturn.Add(Deal(i));
        return deckToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: PullOutValues() implementation???

Comment: This is only a guess, but an educated one: The `PullOutValues` changes the state of the object, and therefor a second call to it will show different results.

Comment: What does `PullOutValues` do? Judging by the name it actually empties the list.

Comment: Could you include the code for `cards.PullOutValues()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your PullOutValues method does something which returns another value if done again. You use the same method in your Text box. In the first example the Text part is using it first, which would cause the second use (in your return) to be empty.

In the second example you put it into a variable with the first method call and return that later. Your Text however would have to be empty in that case. Either way, the second example is the better way, and you should also use deckToReturn instead of calling the method PullOutValues multiple times (it's better practice in general).

Answer (score 0):

Ok found.

The method is called in the textBoxForm.Text assignation, removing the cards that match and returning a deck.
But when I return the method, it do the works a second time... But the first one already removed the cards.